# How to Access attachments from Notes mail?

Tags: c#, lotus-notes

I am want to access attachment of particular mail in Lotus Notes.
I am getting Attachment name with $File.

But i want to extract this attachments and want to save it in user specified path.Using C#.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431546/how-to-get-attachment-value-from-file-item-using-c-lotus-notes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be something similar to below, not sure if I have the correct sintax for c# though.

```
NotesRichTextItem rtitem = doc.GetFirstItem("name")
if ( rtitem.Type = 1) {
  foreach (NotesEmbeddedObject o in rtitem.EmbeddedObjects) {
    if ( o.Type = 1454 ) {
      o.ExtractFile( "c:\samples\" & o.Source )
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Carlos - if you edit your answer and indent your lines of code with four spaces, it will be more readable online.