# How to get Attachment value from "$File" Item? using C# (Lotus Notes)

Tags: c#, lotus-notes

I am trying to access Attachment names form "$File" (Lotus Notes).

```
 NotesView inbox = _serverDatabase.GetView("($Inbox)");
 NotesDocument docInbox = inbox.GetFirstDocument(); 

 NotesItem file = docInbox.GetFirstItem("$File");

 String fileType = file.type.ToString();
```

( getting fileType value "ATTACHMENT" for mail containing attachments)

I am not getting solution given in:

[How to Access attachments from Notes mail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361695/how-to-access-attachments-from-notes-mail)

I got solution as:

```
object[] items = (object[])docInbox.Items; 

foreach (NotesItem nItem in items)

{

  if (nItem.Name == "$FILE")
   {

     NotesItem file = docInbox.GetFirstItem("$File");   

     string fileName = ((object[])nItem.Values) [0].ToString();

     NotesEmbeddedObject attachfile = (NotesEmbeddedObject)docInbox.GetAttachment(fileName);

     if (attachfile != null)
      {
        attachfile.ExtractFile("C:\\test\\" + fileName);
      }
 }
```

But here I am getting only first attachment value.
Can anyone help me out in this?

Comment: The "flag for moderator" is for administrative support, not answers to urgent questions.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
    NotesView inbox = _serverDatabase.GetView("($Inbox)"); 
    NotesDocument docInbox = inbox.GetFirstDocument();  
    if(docInbox.HasEmbedded )   {
       foreach (NotesEmbeddedObject o in docInbox.EmbeddedObjects) {
           if ( o.Type == 1454 ) {
            o.ExtractFile( "c:\samples\" & o.Source )    
    }
   }
}
```

Here is a link to Lotus Notes Designer Help - Really good as you can search for Classes etc to find out what options you have.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.help.domino.designer85.doc/DOC/H_WHAT_S_NEW_IN_RNEXT_CHAP.html

Show you all the methods and properties of various class.

---

Hi Preeti,

OK from the other code sample you are returning an array:

```
string fileName = ((object[])nItem.Values) [0].ToString();
```

Yet you are only selecting the first value, you need to recurse through the collection.

Try something like this.

```
foreach (object attachment in (object[])nItem.Values)
        {
            NotesEmbeddedObject attachfile = (NotesEmbeddedObject)docInbox.GetAttachment(attachment.ToString());

            if (attachfile != null)
            {
                attachfile.ExtractFile("C:\\test\\" + attachment.ToString());
            }

        }
```

Josh

Comment: Hi Mathews,
 I am getting following Errors: :(

Error 1: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator' 



Error 2 : Domino.NotesEmbeddedObject' does not contain a definition for 'Type'


Error 3: Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string' 

Please help me solve it.

Comment: Perhaps you can get the array of NotesEmbeddedObjects first using NotesEmbeddedObject[] embobjs = docInbox.EmbeddedObjects; then use a foreach loop or a for loop to process all objects in the embobjs array.  Also, the third error is because the & operator doesn't mean the same thing in C# as it does in Lotusscript.  You'll need to use the + operator to concatenate strings instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your above code snippet is very helpful to me. So, I tried the to save all attachments and finally found the below solution.

```
            NotesView nInboxDocs = NDb.GetView("$Inbox");
            NDoc=nInboxDocs.GetFirstDocument();
            while (NDoc != null)
            {
                if (NDoc.HasEmbedded && NDoc.HasItem("$File"))
                {
                    // To save only first attachment //
                    //pAttachment = ((object[])NDoc.GetItemValue("$File"))[0].ToString();
                    //pAttachment = CurItem.ToString();
                    //NDoc.GetAttachment(pAttachment).ExtractFile(@"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\" + pAttachment);

                    // To save all attachment //
                    object[] AllDocItems = (object[])NDoc.Items;
                    foreach (object CurItem in AllDocItems)
                    {
                        NotesItem nItem = (NotesItem)CurItem;
                        if (IT_TYPE.ATTACHMENT == nItem.type)
                        {
                            pAttachment = ((object[])nItem.Values)[0].ToString();
                            NDoc.GetAttachment(pAttachment).ExtractFile(@"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\" + pAttachment);
                        }
                    }
                }
                NDoc = nInboxDocs.GetNextDocument(NDoc);
            }
```